# Blender moves and reizes my objects

Tags: rendering, objects, error

Blender resizes and moves my objects when I close the file, and I open it again.
Also when I try it to render it, it gives a different picture than in the object mode.
Why and how could I solve this problem?

For example

In Object mode:
[image]

Rendering:
[image]

It is doing it all the time.

Comment: You have accidentally set keyframes to the location, rotation and scale of the objects. They can be easily deleted by switching to the *Animation* workspace, then in the *Dopesheet* right-click to open the context menu and select *Delete Keyframes*.